# How to draw single line graph using Highchart bullet graph?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have recently switched to highchart and i am trying to achieve a graph like this with the highchart bullet graph

[image]

but failed to customize it like this, Somebody can me define what I'm doing wrong? or is it possible to customize the bullet graph like this or should I move to another graph, Please find the code below.

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  chart: {
    inverted: true,
    marginLeft: 135,
    type: 'bullet'
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderRadius: '10%',
      color: '#819bc2',
      targetOptions: {
        width: '10%'
      }
    }
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  }
});

Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  chart: {
    marginTop: 40
  },
  yAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 150,
      borderRadius: '10%',
      color: '#819bc2'

    }, {
      from: 150,
      to: 225,
      borderRadius: '10%',
      color: '#375e9a'
    }, {
      from: 225,
      to: 9e9,
      borderRadius: '10%',
      color: '#ccd8e9'
    }],
    title: null
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 150,
      target: 250
    }]
  }],
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> (with target at {point.target})'
  }
});
```

```css
#container1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.hc-cat-title {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/bullet.js"></script>
<div id="container1"></div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what part you are having trouble with? You seem to have most of it handled so far...

Comment: If you run my snippet then you can see that the corners are not round, i tried to set `borderRadius: '10%'` on each series but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** - it's possible. Actually the column on your chart is rounded - you can observe that when it's hovered.

You sholud remove plot bands and add two more series instead:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 360,
      target: 300
    }]
  }, {
    data: [{
      y: 280,
      target: 250,
      color: '#c0ffee'
    }]
  }, {
    data: [{
      y: 150,
      target: 250,
      color: '#bada55'
    }]
  }],
```

`grouping` has to be disabled to make series overlapped.

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p2zwf6e8/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/